# After resetting root password, error establishing a database connection

Tags: mysql

I needed to reset my mysql root password and I used these commands: 
 `mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` and  `mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('*****');`.

Then I stopped mysql and restarted and then when I tried to check the website it said: Error establishing a database connection.

I checked if the credential for the table are correct, nothing seemed wrong.

What should I check to fix this issue?

EDITED: I investigated a bit more and I found this: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, does table `NAME` exist in database `wordpress`? It seems from your edit image that thats the problem.

Otherwise: Try making a new user to database, and use the new user and privileges on your wordpress installation:

```
1. CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
2. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
3. FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
(change newsier and password to something else, you choose)
```

This should be entered on the MySQL command line.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I prob forgot o change the password for the database in wordpress.